# DotNetNuke - How can i add module definitions from .dnn6 manifest

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

Hi DotNetNuke experts :)

I want to make some changes in [dnnfeedback](http://dnnfeedback.codeplex.com) source and I want to add module definition to site

in previous release of this module I used to go to "host-->extensions" and from action menu choose "create new module" and simply add the manifest and use it

But in latest module release the manifest extension was changed to `.dnn6` and my DotNetNuke (version:6.1.3) doesn't show me anything to choose from.

I think this section of DotNetNuke Doesn't understand `.dnn6` extension.

so how can I add definition of this module?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you wanna to change a source code just install the package and replace the DLL file with that one you've changed

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use "Install Extension Wizard" instead of "Create new module" option and select the downloaded source package .zip of the Feedback module. It will install source files into DestkopModules/Feedback folder and you can make your changes there.

A little about .dnn6 manifest files can be found [here](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/3091/The-dnn6-Extension-Manifest-File.aspx).